# Device shows up on adb and DDMS, but not on run device list

Tags: android, eclipse

My phone shows up on adb and DDMS but not on the device list when I go to Run.
It is the correct version, it matches the min sdk, and is confirmed on DDMS.

How can I get the device to show up on the Run device list?
Things I've tried:

- I've restarted adb,
- I've restarted eclipse,
- I've restarted my computer (Mac).

Comment: Please check your device cable or try out with changing the device.

Comment: check device when u cannect some papup will come enable debugging

Comment: Debugging is turned on.

Answer (score 1):

Because this is a generic problem there is no simple answer. Best thing you can do is follow something like a checklist.

## Checklist

1. Restart your Android device.

### If restarting does not correct the problem, then try the following

1. Turn USB debugging off then back on again.
   (Optional) turn on "Allow installation of non-market Applications" in Settings.
2. Plug the USB cable into a different USB port on your PC.
3. Unplug/replug the USB cable from your device.
4. Try replacing the USB cable with another one.

### If the above steps fail

1. Go to developers options and "revoke USB debugging Authorization".
2. Unplug/replug the USB cable from your device.

### After all this, we need to get a little more technical.

1) If you were able to see the device connected(ADB devices) , then just try restarting ADB. (commands: adb kill-server, adb start-server) "can't hurt to try right?".

2) If it's still not working , then check the installed usb drivers and if there correct. If not install proper drivers or try reinstalling them.

3) Make sure your "Project Build Target" Android version is supported by your device.

4) Finally play around in the settings for eclipse, try increasing the timeout time for 'ADB connection timeout(ms)', also make sure that you have set the "Deployment target selection mode" to manual.